# Android: Loading image using Glide leaves whitespace on both ends

Tags: android, android-glide

I am loading image from server using Glide. The image size is 600 X 400px. Now my image view is as follows

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView76"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_eight"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_eight"
     android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_eight"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     app:bindImageUrl="@{newsModel.images}"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

This is how I am loading image:

```
Glide.with(view.context).asBitmap().load(imageUrl).apply(RequestOptions().optionalCenterInside()).into(view)
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

As show, white space appears on both ends of image. How can I make this image use full width of imageview, while maintaining aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

`androd:scaleType=“fit_xy”`
you this add to imageviewthis attribute 
It will help you the image full the whole ImageView

Comment: This does not respects aspect ratio.

Comment: yes,Because your picture is not wide enough to fill the entire ImageView control. So if you want to fill it, you have to stretch the picture to fill the entire control. Of course, this will distort the width and height of the picture. If you want to fill the entire imageview control. You can't fix the width and height of ImageViwe, so it can also be full of imageview controls. In contrast, your layout may deviate